# Can't install synaptic in kali

Tags: linux, debian, terminal, kali-linux, synaptic

Following is the error while installing synaptic

```
*Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libfolks25 : Breaks: libfolks-eds25 (< 0.8.0-2~) but 0.6.9-1+b1 is to be installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.****
```

Comment: What's the output of `dpkg --get-selections | grep hold`?

Comment: nothing happened

Comment: OK, that means that it's not "caused by held packages" as the error message implies it might be.

Comment: what should i do now ?

Answer (score 0):

Seeing this error, I guess you used `apt` to install synaptic.

Sometimes, `apt` faces errors about dependencies, and can't fix them. If you want to fix this errors and force install synaptic, you have to first install `aptitude` (an equivalent to `apt`) with the command `apt-get install aptitude`.

Then use `aptitude` to install `synaptic` with the command `aptitude install synaptic`. It will tell you that there is an error with dependencies (like `apt` told you), but it will also propose solutions to fix the errors and install the package you want. Each time it provide you with a solution, read it, then press `y` if you accept that solution, or `n` to show another solution, until you find the solution where `synaptic` will be installed.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50733/discussion-on-answer-by-sidahmed-cant-install-synaptic-in-kali).

Answer (score -1):

Messing up with repositories or using experimental repositories also led to this error.

If you're using debian only use the appropriate repositories provided by the distro

Type:-

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Debian :-

```
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian stable main contrib non-free
```

Kali :-

```
deb http://http.kali.org/kali kali-rolling main non-free contrib
```

And

```
sudo apt update
```

The error above clearly shows that you're using a experimental repository.

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
```